# sed get mutiple options error during replacing a word in batch files

Tags: linux, bash, replace, sed, redhat

When I'm trying to replace a string in several files, I tried to use sed, but it seem something wrong during the replace procedure.
my input is:

```
sed -i "s/keywords_extraction/group_knapsack/g"'grep keywords_extraction -rl ./'
```

and this is what I got:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 39: multiple `g' options to `s' command
```

the vesion of sed is 4.1.5

Comment: well you have a grep command in the middle of it...

Comment: @123 I have seen a lot of articles describing like this way

Comment: @123 I found that I used the error `, I think it's '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you are trying something like this :

```
sed -i "s/keywords_extraction/group_knapsack/g" $(grep keywords_extraction -rl ./)
```

(OR)

```
sed -i "s/keywords_extraction/group_knapsack/g" `grep keywords_extraction -rl ./`
```

Comment: yes, I found that I was mislead by the `` and '', could you tell me what's the difference?

Comment: @maple, Whatever command inside `(Back tick)` Or `$()` will be executed and output will be returned. In your case, `grep` will be executed and will output a list of files (because, you specified `-l` option). Then, `sed` will work with those files.

Answer (score 2):

```
find -type f -exec sed -i 's/keywords_extraction/group_knapsack/g' {} +
```

This would take care of filenames with special characters like spaces too. However, this has the side effect of changing modification time of even those files not containing the search pattern